# changing <select> options using jquery .change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm facing this problem for more than 3 hours as I'm a still learning javascript and jquery..
I want to change select options based on user's choice from the same select input..
I don't know how to explain well but see this http://jsfiddle.net/YKASE/

THE HTML:

```
<select name="test" class="select" id="test" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;">
<option value="1" class="first">1</option>
<option value="2" class="first">2</option>
<option value="3" class="first">3</option>
<option value="a" id="1" class="hidden second">a</option>
<option value="b" id="1" class="hidden second">b</option>
<option value="c" id="1" class="hidden second">c</option>
<option value="x" id="2" class="hidden second">x</option>
<option value="y" id="2" class="hidden second">y</option>
<option value="z" id="2" class="hidden second">z</option>
<option value="baz" id="3" class="hidden second">baz</option>
<option value="bar" id="3" class="hidden second">bar</option>
<option value="foo" id="3" class="hidden second">foo</option>
</select>
```

THE JS:

```
$("select#test").change(function () {
    $("#" + $(this).val()).removeClass("hidden");
    $(".first").addClass("hidden");
});
```

THE CSS:

```
.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

The problem is that only one option is shown but I want to show them all..

Comment: **HTML does not permit duplicate element IDs.** Use classes instead.

Comment: first problem is that you can't have multiple elements with same id ( you have 3 options with the same id "1")

Comment: thanks..
I didn't notice that..

Comment: I changed it to classes and it worked..
thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a custom attribute to the options and keep the same values throughout the group.

```
<select name="test" class="select" id="test" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;">
    <option data-index="1" value="1" class="first">1</option>
    <option data-index="1" value="2" class="first">2</option>
    <option data-index="1" value="3" class="first">3</option>
    <option data-index="2" value="a" id="1" class="hidden second">a</option>
    <option data-index="2" value="b" id="1" class="hidden second">b</option>
    <option data-index="2" value="c" id="1" class="hidden second">c</option>
    <option data-index="2" value="x" id="2" class="hidden second">x</option>
    <option data-index="2" value="y" id="2" class="hidden second">y</option>
    <option data-index="2" value="z" id="2" class="hidden second">z</option>
    <option data-index="2" value="baz" id="3" class="hidden second">baz</option>
    <option data-index="2" value="bar" id="3" class="hidden second">bar</option>
    <option data-index="2" value="foo" id="3" class="hidden second">foo</option>
</select>


$("select#test").change(function () {
    //get the data-index attribute of the selected option
    var nIndex =     $('option[value= '+ $(this).val()+']').attr('data-index');
    //get all elements with the attribute data-index = nIndex
    $('option[data-index= '+ nIndex +']').removeClass("hidden");
    $(".first").addClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: data value can be retrieved with [`.data("index")`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).